# Wcf service reference differs in 2 projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, wcf

I am creating a battleships game in C#. for this game i currently have 3 projects:

1. A WPF application which represents the client
2. An ASP.NET MVC application which functions as the lobby where clients login to and start a game with each other
3. A WCF Service, which is hosted where both applications can use to communicate with each other.

In both the WPF and MVC application a service reference is created for the WCF service. However the service reference looks different in both application.
Btw the service also implements a callback service.

In the WPF application i can simply create a service client and add the current instance context to be the instance where the callback service is called at like:

```
var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
lobbyserviceClient = new LobbyServiceClient(instanceContext);
```

And the service works fine.

However in the MVC application the service reference has completely different constructors of which none of them seem to work fine.Underneath is an example of the reference file:

```
    public LobbyServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            this(new LobbyServiceClientCallback(), binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    private LobbyServiceClient(LobbyServiceClientCallback callbackImpl, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(new System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext(callbackImpl), binding, remoteAddress)
    {
        callbackImpl.Initialize(this);
    }
```

Has anybody encountered this problem before or maybe sees something is wrong and knows the solution.

p.s. Also when trying to use the first constructor as shown above. Only the BasicHTTPBinding is available in my system.servicemodel namespace where as in the WCF service a WSDualHttpBinding is used which is why an error is thrown when trying to use this contructor

Comment: sorry no idea, but your project description drive to the following ; I would better make a web api with websocket (instead of wcf) and no MVC/ASP application...?!?! bye

Comment: Thanks, i would have made a different structure as well but its a school project which requires us to do it that way:(

Comment: Ok. One tip : with WCF do not use the "add web reference" of visual. Make 2 assembly/project where you define the service interface  with ServiceContract attribute and model with [DataContract]-[DataMember] attributes. Then add project reference in client project.

Answer (score 0):

to complete my comments, search for "wcf sample with no web reference" ==> see

[this sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113176/How-to-use-a-WCF-Service-without-adding-Service-Re) or [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-a-wcf-service-without-adding-service-reference/)